# GridView in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, gridview, aqgridview

I am working on an iPhone application in which I have to design a GridView, I have searched on google + stackoverflow and found that one possible solution is AQGridView, I have tried it but all of its examples are not working in XCode 4.1.

The error I am facing is: Expected ':', ",", ";", "}" or '*attribute*' before '_dataSource'.
The line causing this error is `id<AQGridViewDataSource>        __unsafe_unretained _dataSource;` (line no 100 in AQGridView.m).

What I am trying to achieve is to display buttons in 2x4 table.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit**

Ok, so I have downloaded Xcode 4.2 as some guys suggested in comments, now the previous errors are gone but I am having a new on `__bridge Undeclared (first use in this function)`, the line causing this error is line no 961 in AQGridView.m ([Source Code](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView/blob/master/Classes/AQGridView.m#L961))

Thanks

Comment: Please post the relevant section of the code

Comment: This is because it uses [ARC](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) which requires Xcode 4.2. Why not upgrade?

Comment: @omz: Probably because he has a Snow Leopard like thousands of other developers, who would love to use XCode 4.2 and who can't.

Comment: @Jens: Xcode 4.2 is also available for Snow Leopard. Only 4.2.1 isn't, but that shouldn't make much of a difference.

Comment: Oh - I thought, that 4.2 requires a Lion - for my side, I will update then.

Comment: Ok, I am using Xcode 4.1 on Lion, I never knew there was new version available. I will download and let you guys know, Thanks for helping.

Comment: I have Edited the question, please help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First create a gridview objective class.write own delgate and datasource methods as tableview in it.call it in the viewcontrler class.

Answer (score -1):

I think, on XCode 4.2 this is not an issue.
XCode 4.1 does not know __unsafe_unretained.
So just define it in some global project header:

```
#define __unsafe_unretained
```

and try to compile again.